# SharePoint REST API _api/web/currentuser Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation

Tags: permissions, api, shareoint

I'm doing Office365 account-based login functionality through SharePoint on PHP.
After doing that I was able to login and get the **SPAppToken** and **SPSiteUrl**
I use them to get the **refreshToken**, then I get the **accessToken** based on the **refreshToken**

Continue to trying to get the information of the logged in user but failed.
Information is as follows:

```
URL: https://mypage.sharepoint.com/_api/web/currentuser
Method: GET
Headers:
Accept: application/json; odata=verbose
Authorization: Bearer + accessToken
```

Result:

```
{
     "error": {
         "code": "-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException",
         "message": {
             "lang": "ja-JP",
             "value": "Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation."
         }
     }
}
```

I don't know what to do to be able to get my own credentials API, please help, I think I need somewhere to give permission, but I don't know where it is!
Thanks everyone!

Comment: Is this user having permissions on the respective SharePoint site?

Comment: @GaneshSanap yes!  the account I'm testing with has permissions "Full control"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already know my cause!
Because I have not given permission for my login Add-In to create.

I did step 1, but not done step 2

**Step 1:**

Go to the URL and create the Add-in.
Copy **Client Id** and **Client Secret**.
And click button **Create**
https://mypage.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx

[image]

**Step: 2**
Go to the URL:
https://mypage.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx

Paste Client Id to App Id
And paste XML:

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web" Right="Read" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

Click button **Create**
[image]

Continue click **Trust It** and Done

[image]